# Printing Unicode Characters in Python (with '\x00')

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to print unicode characters in python.

What is happening:

```
$ python -c "print u'TEXT'" | xxd
0000000: 5445 5854 0a                             TEXT.
```

Expected:

```
$ python -c "print u'TEXT'" | xxd
0000000: 5400 4500 5800 5400 0a                   T.E.X.T..
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python converts Unicode strings into bytes before printing. What you see is the correct output e.g., `b'T' == b'\x54'`:

```
$ python -c"print u'TEXT'.encode('ascii')" | xxd
0000000: 5445 5854 0a                             TEXT.
```

Don't confuse Unicode string and a bytestring encoded in UTF-16 character encoding:

```
$ python -c"print u'TEXT'.encode('utf-16le')" | xxd
0000000: 5400 4500 5800 5400 0a                   T.E.X.T..
```

You could use `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to change the character encoding used to encode the output for the whole script:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-16le python -c"print u'TEXT'" | xxd
0000000: 5400 4500 5800 5400 0a                   T.E.X.T..
```